# Unable to update packages due errors of corrupted cache files

Tags: pi-3, apt, update, packages, raspberry-pi-os-bullseye

When I my trying to update packages by "sudo apt update" I have got the errors:
Hit:1 http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian bullseye InRelease
Hit:2 http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian bullseye InRelease
Reading package lists... Error!
E: Unable to parse package file /var/lib/apt/lists/raspbian.raspberrypi.org_raspbian_dists_bullseye_main_binary-armhf_Packages (1)
W: You may want to run apt-get update to correct these problems
E: The package cache file is corrupted

Using sudo apt-get update does not help. What would be the way to make the update process workign again ?

Comment: Personally I would `sudo rm -rf /var/lib/apt/*` to clear out that directory.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this problem on my RPi, and running `sudo rm -rf /var/lib/apt/*` worked for me right away. I was hesitant to run it because I've never used this command, but it worked. My Raspbian OS is now running flawlessly.